# How can I combine 3 columns into one

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have 3 columns called product_one, product_two and product_three and I want to combine all of them into one.

```
From this:

|product_one | product_two | product_three |
|------------------------------------------|
|spoon       | phone       | knife
|fork        | case        |

To this:

|products| 
|--------
|spoon   |  
|fork    | 
|phone   |
|case    |
|knife   |
```

How is this possible in sql?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select products from your_table 
unpivot (products for col in (product_one, product_two, product_three))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Another option that does not require specifying column names:

```
select split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] products
from your_table t,
unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv
where split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] != 'null'
```

Yet another one -

```
select trim(value) products
from your_table t,
unnest(split(trim(format('%t', t), '()'))) value
where trim(value) != 'NULL'
```

all with same output

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.product_one 
from your_table t
  union all
select t2.product_two
from your_table t2
  union all
select t3.product_three
from your_table t3
```

Answer (score 0):

By union:
select a.product_one as pr from a where a.product_one is not null
union
select b.product_two as pr from b where b.product_two is not null
union
select c.product_three as pr from c where c.product_three is not null

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).